# Python close children subprocess

Tags: python, windows, web-services, file, web-applications

I have a very simple question on killing child subprocesses in scripts written in python 3.

Where,

If I have,

```
my_process = None

def open_storage():
    my_process = subprocess.Popen("waffles.exe")

def kill_children():
    my_process.kill()
```

After calling `open_storage()`, if I call `kill_children()`, I get

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kill'`

But if I have,

my_process = None

```
my_process = subprocess.Popen("waffles.exe")

def kill_children():
    my_process.kill()
```

Everything works fine.

Can anyone explain this strange behaviour? I need to have `open_storage()` as a function because it's designed to be triggered by a tkinter button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use global, otherwise it will use a local variable.

```
def open_storage():
    global my_process
    my_process = subprocess.Popen("waffles.exe")
```