# Python limit maximum allowed subprocesses opened

Tags: python, windows, web-services, file, web-applications

Hello Everyone. Earlier I had a question about killing children subprocesses in Python 3. The thread is here > [Python close children subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756977/python-close-children-subprocess) and the working code is as follows:

```
def open_storage():
    global my_process
    my_process = subprocess.Popen("waffles.exe")

def kill_children():
    my_process.kill()
```

Now I have another question. How do I limit the maxiumum number of allowed subprocesses spawned? I know with Linux you can simply use ulimit, as described in a thread found here > [Python: ulimit and nice for subprocess.call / subprocess.Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689505/python-ulimit-and-nice-for-subprocess-call-subprocess-popen)

Where the linux method is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ulimit -t 60; nice -n 15 cpuhog', shell=True)
```

Is there a way of 'ulimit' in Windows?

Thanks.